# Modal Form Not Showing in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have the the following modal that I am trying to use as a Create/Edit form for my SQLite3 data but nothing ever appears. I can connect this form to it's own URL and that works fine, but I am looking to include it within the same /communications url just as a pop-up (enabling the user to stay on the same screen and quickly fill out the form).

EDIT: I have pinpointed the issue to the views.communications piece. It looks like I cannot load both the list of data used for my data table AND the form needed to create the data. Any ideas how to re-write this piece to make both work?

[image]

models.py

```
class Communications(models.Model):
    team = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.communication
```

forms.py

```
class CommunicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communications
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
    path('communications/', views.CommunicationsView.as_view(), name='communications'),
```

views.py

```
def communications(request):
    comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('polls/communications.html')
    context = {
        'comms_list': comms_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    if request.method == "POST":
        return render(request,'polls/communications.html',{"form":CommunicationsForm,"info":"Done"})
    else:
        return render(request,'polls/communications.html',{"form":CommunicationsForm})
```

polls/communications.html:

```
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form}}
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do...In order have the form in every template you need to use `context_preprocessor`

Comment: Does using a modal (bootstrap or other) for the pop up bit, and add a a post method to your class work? Also not exactly sure which part you are having the issue with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what the end result currently is.... The modal pops up, but the CommunicationsForm() does not show

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Updated with a more targeted question

Answer (score 0):

The way you create a modal is entirely wrong. The `modal-footer` need to be placed outside the `modal-body`. It should be more like this,

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
```

Please refer [bootstrap documentation about modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

And in your views.py the statements after the [`return`](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/) will not execute

```
def communications(request):
    comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('polls/communications.html')
    context = {
        'comms_list': comms_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

so the views.py must look like this(still not sure is this the process you want. anyway...),

```
def communications(request):
    comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('polls/communications.html')
        
    context = {
        'comms_list': comms_list,
        'form': form,
    }
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommunicationsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # and other operations like redirecting
            ...
            return redirect(...)
            
    else:
        form = CommunicationsForm()

    return render(request, 'polls/communications.html', context)
```